# Internal Mechanism and Efficiency of the 'DISTINCT' Keyword in SQL

Tags: sql, database, data-structures, time-complexity

Can anyone give me a detailed explanation on the operational mechanics and time complexity of the 'DISTINCT' keyword.

I actually researched about this, My efforts to uncover precise information on this topic have so far been fruitless.

Comment: What is the exact question, that is not explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dmx/select-distinct-from-model-dmx?view=sql-server-ver16  AND/OR here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/distinct-clause-in-ms-sql-server/  AND/OR here: https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-select-distinct/ ??

Comment: This would change depending on the database engine (and version). Which database are you using?

Comment: Moreover the engines are smart enough to detect already distinct result sets (maybe the PK is already there), sorted ones (easy to distinct), fully random ones (materialize-sort/materialize-hash?) Different internal operators could be very efficient or not at all. What's the specific query?

Comment: "My efforts to uncover precise information on this topic have so far been fruitless." what efforts what did you find? Which DBMS are you talking about for a start? Is the table indexed? Is the data in the correct order already or does it need sorting or hashing? This is hopelessly vague.

Comment: Long and short of it: `DISTINCT` is just a `GROUP BY` with no aggregation so the same calculations will apply. The compiler will detect if the data is already sorted. If so it can just aggregate the stream as it goes. Otherwise it must either sort it first then aggregate, or hash it. Which of those it picks will depend on DBMS, and things like statistics and parallelization etc. More detail on a specific case would help us answer this better.

Answer (score 0):

The optimizer will choose appropriate operators to do the DISTINCT operation depending on the structure of the database, mainly the table involved.

As an exemple, if the expression to DISTINCT is involved into a PRIMARY KEY, a UNIQUE constraint or an UNIQUE index, the final operation in the query execution plan will be to do nothing... Because the distinct does exists naturally.

If the cardinalty of the table is low, the most common way to do DISTINCT is a sort or an aggregate, otherwise a hash is computed and the algorithm is to treats hash buckets. Those algorithms (sort, agegate and hash) can be parallelized on RDBMS that supports those features like SQL Server...

**CASE 1 - DISTINCT without naturally UNIQUE**

```
CREATE TABLE T_NUM (N INT );
INSERT INTO T_NUM VALUES (1)
DECLARE @I INT = 1;
WHILE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM T_NUM WHERE N = 100)
   INSERT INTO T_NUM SELECT MAX(N) + 1 FROM T_NUM;
```

[image: Execution plan without unique]

A sort is done

**CASE 2 - DISTINCT without naturally UNIQUE but more rows**

```
TRUNCATE TABLE T_NUM
INSERT INTO T_NUM VALUES (1)
DECLARE @I INT = 1;
WHILE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM T_NUM WHERE N = 10000)
   INSERT INTO T_NUM SELECT MAX(N) + 1 FROM T_NUM;
```

[image: Execution plan without unique but more rows (10.000)]

A hash is done

**CASE 3 - DISTINCT without naturally UNIQUE but much more rows**

```
TRUNCATE TABLE T_NUM
DECLARE @I INT = 1;
WHILE @I <= 1000000
BEGIN   
   INSERT INTO T_NUM VALUES (@I);
   SET @I +=1;
END;
```

[image: Execution plan without unique but much more rows (1.000.000)]

Hash operation with parallelism

**CASE 4 - DISTINCT with naturally UNIQUE**

```
ALTER TABLE T_NUM ADD CONSTRAINT U UNIQUE (N);
```

[image: Execution plan with unique]

Nothing to do...

**CASE 5 - DISTINCT without naturally UNIQUE but an index**

```
ALTER TABLE T_NUM DROP CONSTRAINT U;
CREATE INDEX X ON T_NUM (N);
```

[image: Execution plan with agregate]

Agregate with no paralelism

All those example has been done on Microsoft SQL Server (the one used for stackoverflow...)

Comment: I think it's more the statistics on number of output distinct values expected that makes that change, rather than purely the number of overall input rows.